# Search for file formats + options

Tags: bash, shell, find

I was fiddling around with bash last month and am trying to create a script.

I want the script to search through the folders for files with some kind of extension defined by the argument -e. The folders are defined without -option. The output is 2 columns where in the first it prints the found files, and in the second the respective folders.

Is this the most efficient and/or flexible way to go?

I also can't manage to let the -l command work. Any idea what's wrong? When I enter `-name \${CHAR}*`, it simply doesn't work. Also, how can I make it recognize a range being used? With an if-function looking for the "-" character or something?

I think I managed to mount a block device, but how can I add the path as a parameter so it can be used as a folder? Setting a number as a var doesn't work, it tells me it doesn't recognize the command.

For some reason the 'no recursion' tag works, but the 'no numbers' doesn't. I have no idea why this would be different.

When using the 'no recursion' `(nn)` and 'no numbers' `(nr)` tags I use a long tag `--tag` for the arguments. Is it possible to use only 1 `-tag`? This is possible with get opts, but then I can't manage to use the other tags after the get opts has been used. Someone a solution?

Finally, is it possible, when finding 2 files with the same file name, instead of printing the file twice, can it just show the file once. But for every file with the same name keep a white space, so it can still show all the folders in the second column?

```
#!/bin/bash

#FUNCTIONS
#Error
#Also written to stderr
err() {
  echo 1>&2;
  echo "Error, not enough arguments" 1>&2;
  echo "Usage: $0 [-e <file extension>] [<folder>]";
  echo "Please enter the argument -e and at least 1 folder.";
  echo "More: Please chek Help by using -h or --help.";
  echo 1>&2;
  exit
 }

#Help
help() {
  echo
  echo "--- Help ---"
  echo
  echo "This script will look for file extentions in 1 or more directories. The output shows the found files with the according folder where it's located."
  echo
  echo "Argument -e <ext> is required."
  echo "Other arguments the to-look-trough folders."
  echo
  echo "These are also usable options:"
  echo "-h or --help shows this."
  echo "-l <character> looks for files starting with the character."
  echo "-l <character1>-<character2> does the same, but looks trough a range of characters."
  echo "-b <block-device> mounts a partition to /mnt and let it search through."
  echo "--nn (no numbers) makes sure there are no numbers in the file name."
  echo "--nr (no recursion) doesn't look trough subdirectories."
  echo "-r of –-err <file> writes the errors (f.e. corrupted directory) to <file>."
  echo "-s <word> searches the word through the files and only shows the files having that word."
  echo
  exit
}

#VARS

#execute getopt
OPTS=$(getopt -o e:hl:b:r:s: -l "help,nn,nr,err" -n "FileExtensionScript" -- "$@");

#Bad arguments
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
  err;
  exit
fi

#Rearrange arguments
eval set -- "$OPTS";

#echo "AFTER SET -- \$OPTS: $@";

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -e)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        EXT=$1;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    -h|--help)
      shift;
      help;
      ;;
    -l)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        CHAR=$1;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    -b)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        sudo mkdir /mnt/$1;
        sudo echo -e "/dev/$1       /mnt/$1           vfat    defaults        0       0 " >> /etc/fstab;
        sudo mount -a;
        999=/mnt/$1;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    --nn)
      shift;
      NONUM=" ! -name '*[0-9]*'";
      ;;
    --nr)
      shift;
      NOREC="-maxdepth 1";
      ;;
    -f|--err)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        ERROR="| 2>filename | tee -a $1";
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    -s)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        SEARCH="-name '*$1*'";
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    --)
      shift;
      break;
      ;;
  esac
done

#No folder or arguments given
if [ $# -lt 1 ];
then
  err;
  exit
fi

#Debug
echo "Folder argumenten: $@" >2;
echo \# $# >2;

#Create arrays with found files and according folders
FILES=( $(find $@ $NOREC $SEARCH $NONUM -name \*.${EXT} $ERROR | rev | cut -d/ -f 1 | rev) )
FOLDERS=( $(find $@ $NOREC $SEARCH $NONUM -name \*.${EXT} $ERROR | rev | cut -d/ -f 1 --complement | rev) )
#Show arrays in 2 columns
for ((i = 0; i <= ${#FILES[@]}; i++));
do
    printf '%s %s\n' "${FILES[i]}" "${FOLDERS[i]}"
done | column -t | sort -k1 #Make columns cleaner + sort on filename
```

I am not native English speaker and am hoping to get some tips to finish my script :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to add `-type d` or `-type f` to help differentiate between directrories and files.

Comment: Be more specific in what you're asking.   "Setting a number as a var doesn't work, it tells me it doesn't recognize the command." - you want a var with a name of a number? not possible. but you can use an array, with the numbers as index into it.